# Need help with debugging Error: Definition of base has to precede definition of derived contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain, evm, smart-contract-wallets, inheritance

I'm working on a social account recovery feature for smart accounts (ERC-4337) on top of Thirdweb's smart account contract.

[Link to the codebase](https://github.com/alfheimrShiven/thridweb-contracts/tree/account-social-recovery)

I'm getting the error `Base has to precede definition of derived contract` on `Account.sol` contract:

```
Error (2449): Definition of base has to precede definition of derived contract
  --> contracts/prebuilts/account/non-upgradeable/Account.sol:36:21:
   |
36 | contract Account is AccountCore, ContractMetadata, ERC1271, ERC721Holder, ERC1155Holder {
   |
```

I understand what this error means, but dont seem not to be able to resolve this.

Hoping to get another pair of eyes to look at the `Account.sol` contract and its inheritance structure to spot the issue. This would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

*Side note: I'm also looking out for Smart Contract devs who would like to collaborate on this project, so do show your interest if you want to work on [ERC-4337.](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4337)*

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't change the inheritance tree structure, instead of using a functional call I used the low-level `contractAddress.call{value: 2 ethers}("")` function for calling the contract. That removed the use of the inherited contract by the base contract, thus resolving the error.

Comment: Hi! You might want to edit the question for clarity - I only realized from the answer that the deployment was working, and the only issue was a specific contract call. I'd recommend including the code for the function being called, and the function calling it. Cheers!